# Alter MySQL table varchar fields to decimal fields : Truncated incorrect DECIMAL value

Tags: mysql

I need convert in my table of DB MySQL the column values from **VARCHAR(255)** to **DECIMAL (10,5)**.

I have tried this SQL query in which first replace **','** with **'.'** and then set new the column values to **DECIMAL (10,5)**:

```
[SQL]UPDATE `doTable`
SET doAV = REPLACE (doAV, ',', '.')
WHERE
    YEAR (`doDate`) IN (YEAR(CURDATE()));
Affected rows: 83169
Time: 1.846s

[SQL]
ALTER TABLE `doTable` MODIFY COLUMN doAV DECIMAL (10, 5);
[Err] 1292 - Truncated incorrect DECIMAL value: '2226,000'
```

But I have error:

```
[Err] 1292 - Truncated incorrect DECIMAL value: '2226,000'
```

How to do resolve this?

Can you help me?

Thank you in advance for any help, really appreciated.

**#Edit 01**

```
+----------+
| doAV     |
+----------+
| 2226.000 |
| 2226.00  |
| 2225.750 |
| 2225.600 |
| 2225.533 |
| 2225.250 |
| 2225.000 |
| 2225.00  |
| 2224.800 |
| 2224.667 |
+----------+
```

**#Edit 02**

```
+-----------+
| doAV      |
+-----------+
| 2226.000  |
| 792.000   |
| 338.400   |
| 13635.000 |
| 1438.125  |
| 220.800   |
| 172.000   |
| 253.000   |
| 4258.500  |
| 352.800   |
+-----------+
```

Comment: share some sample data from your table (doAV values)

Comment: @KMS thanks for reply, please see **#Edit 01** in my first question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you updated only rows in `YEAR (doDate) IN (YEAR(CURDATE()))`. Try to update all the rows first of all. Delete `WHERE` condition from your `UPDATE` and run it again.

Try to check only the whole part

```
SELECT *
FROM doTable
WHERE LENGTH(LEFT(doAV,IFNULL(NULLIF(LOCATE('.',doAV)-1,-1),LENGTH(doAV))))>5
```

`DECIMAL(10, 5)` => your whole part can containt only 5 digitals (10-5=5).

Comment: Thank you now the error is [Err] 1264 - Out of range value for column 'doAV' at row 2579

Comment: Check your data - `select * from doTable where LENGTH('doAV')>10`

Comment: Empty set in output sql query... the column values is **VARCHAR(255)**

Comment: Try to check only the whole part `SELECT * FROM doTable WHERE LEFT(doAV,LOCATE('.',doAV)-1)>5`. `DECIMAL(10, 5)` => your whole part can containt only 5 digitals `(10-5=5)`.

Comment: thanks for reply, please see **#Edit 02** in my first question-

Comment: Try my last from my answer. I updated it. The query from my comment was wrong.